# ASP.NET MVC 5 IIS web garden every request change Session ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

Session ID changes when I use a Web Garden. A Web Garden is a configuration of IIS that allows multiple worker processes to run simultaneously. The number of worker processes can be specified in the application pool settings of IIS.

When I use a Web Garden, each request can be routed to a different worker process, and thus the Session ID will change. This is because each worker process has its own Session State store, so when the request is routed to a different process, it will get a different Session ID

How to prevent this from happening ?

How to prevent Session ID changes from happening ?

Comment: For decades people use other modes than In-Process mode to solve that, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178586(v=vs.100)

Comment: Each worker process has its own thread and memory space in web garden, if the application uses in-process session variables, the application will not function correctly, because the same user requests are picked up by different worker processes that do not share the same session details.

Comment: Refer:
https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/iis/web-garden-and-web-farm